# How to use GWT and ORM together

Tags: java, database, hibernate, gwt, orm

This [article](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/using_gwt_with_hibernate.html) describes problems and solution how to use GWT and Hibernate together. I just wonder whether there are newer ways to implement the example from the [article](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/using_gwt_with_hibernate.html), because it is from 2009? Or are there other ORM avaible which works better with GWT?